# HQL Query, LocalDateTime condition

Tags: hql, spring-data, jpql

I have a model that have a `LocalDateTime` property, the values of this property in the db looks like this: `2015-01-22 00:00:00`, I want to do an hql query where the date is equal to the db date, without having to specify the clock.

i.e. in SQL, I can do:

```
WHERE published_departure_date_local='2015-1-22';
```

This will return the result with the following date: `2015-01-22 00:00:00`

in HQL, it expects me to send a `LocalDateTime` object, which needs to have the clock set but I don't know the clock at the time of the query.

I tried passing a `LocalDate` in the hql query, but it complains because the model property is `LocalDateTime` and I'm passing `LocalDate` in the `WHERE` clause.

Should I switch to native sql queries? I prefer to keep all hql if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Spring Data JPA?

Assuming from your question's tags that you are, one of the things you can do is use Between clause, with date1 as `2015-01-22 00:00:00` and date2 as `2015-01-22 23:59:59`.

From Table 4 from Spring Data [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/reference/html/),

Sample: `findByStartDateBetween`

JPQL snippet: `… where x.startDate between 1? and ?2`

Comment: This works, just tried it. Even though it requires a bit more code (to generate the start of the day and the end). Maybe there is another way without using `between`? Anyway I'm fine for now, thanks.